# Drupal 9/10 - How to save a Views Global Text field value

Tags: view, drupal

I have a View with a Global Text field that computes a value from various node fields.  I want to automatically save the computed value into a node field if possible.

Any idea how can I do that please?

Thanks for your time and thoughts.

Comment: try [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_presave/10)